# Changing sides in tennis

Tags: rules, tennis

This [site](https://www.livestrong.com/article/142038-tennis-rules-switching-sides/) says:

> A player has to win six games, and at least two more than the foe, to claim a tennis match. Players switch sides after every odd game, as in the first, third and fifth games, and so on. Players also switch sides at the end of a set if they're playing an odd number of games.

So, you start, 1-0, and change sides. If the game ends 6-0, 6-2 or 6-4 (or an even number of games), you play the first game of the new set, change sides, and you are back to the previous rule.

But what if a player wins 6-1 or 6-3? You win the set, then change sides. Now, you play a new set, do you change again at 1-0 (therefore after having played just one game), or wait until the 1-1 or 2-0, therefore now changing after an even number of games in the second set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They switch at the end of the set, AND at the end of the first game, you are reading it correctly. Here are some pictures of it happening in the 2014 Australian Open Semis between Nadal and Federer ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7AiwWwiF_k))

Nadal (red) is at the top, in the 9th game of the set.
[image]

He won the set, and they switched sides for the start of the first game. He is now on the bottom.
[image]

After the first game, being an odd-numbered game, they switch again and Nadal is back on the top of the screen.
[image]

No switching to even-numbered games needed!